# Get immediate file name copied using Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Scenario:
Need to know the filename which was copied from source to destination using copy activity of azure data factory.

Problem :
Get metadata can be used for getting the file name. But how do we know which file is copied if more then one file is present in the folder.

Comment: You can add columns like filepath now within the Copy activity using the `$$FILEPATH` syntax.  See the docs for [more examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy).  Post back if you need a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to filter by last modified time. Start time use this expression:

```
@activity('Copy data1').output.executionDetails[0].start
```

End time use `@utcnow()`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below process in case if you want to achieve the requirement via in built ADF activities else it can be easily achieved by python(Azure functions) or csutom activity.

1. Create 2 variables :
   MaxLastProcessedDate = 1900-01-01
   LatestFile
2. Use GetMetaDataActivity at folder level to get the list of childItems
3. Use the output of the childitems field as input to a foreach loop activity
4. Within Foreach :
   a) GetMetaDataActivity at file level (since each iteration would be for each file)
   b) If condition activity  (if lastmodifieddate of getmetadata activity > MaxLastProcessedDate)
   for true: update the MaxLastProcessedDate variable to the lastmodifieddate of getmetadata activity  and update the LatestFile variable to file name of that iteration.