Azure EventGrid batching delay
When using EventGrid to subscribe to BlobCreated events, then calling an Azure Function to process that batch, how long does EventGrid wait until it delivers the batch?
I want to receieve BlobCreated events after Azure Data Factory is done copying them from a fileserver, but I don't think ADF can guarantee that all the blobs appear in parallel at the same time in blob storage, so the solution I came up with in the end was to call my Azure Function from ADF after the copy activity is done.
I found this comment in the docs which seems to answer my question?

Event Grid doesn't delay events to create a batch if fewer events are available.

I also read here that my function is invoked per element in the batch array? That would obviously defeat the whole purpose of batching...
What are my options to avoid using an HTTP trigger and calling it from ADF?
I considered using a StorageQueue to store EventGrid messages, then trigger my function on a new queue item, and then wait for a minute until the queue is filled up, then start processing the events. This seemed to actually work, but reading 32 messages per request until I got 1000 messages to process felt quite slow...
I couldn't think of a better way to do this, until I decided that for our specific usecase it's enough to have an HTTP triggered function that is called by ADF. The queue solution would be ideal because with the HTTP trigger, I cannot scale out to multiple instances or else there might be race conditions in where a second instance is reading and processing the same blob, but for our usecase this seems to be enough.
Thanks

You can use blob trigger, try it once.

As an alternate suggestion you can use the blob trigger function on the copy activity log files, this will invoke the function for every batch of records.
First, you need to enable the logs in copy activity settings.

After enabling logging, you give storage linked service in connection.
Logging level to Info based on the details required you set it.
Next, logging mode as Best effort, this mode logs the details for batch of records, then give the storage path.
After completion of copy activity, in the Json output
the log file path will be present

or in your storage account path like below.
https://[your-blob-account].blob.core.windows.net/[logFilePath]/copyactivity-logs/[copy-activity-name]/[copy-activity-run-id]/[auto-generated-GUID].txt

This is the schema of the log file you can use it in you function to check the files written and skipped.
Next, you give the folder path till your copy activity name
https://[your-blob-account].blob.core.windows.net/[logFilePath]/copyactivity-logs/[copy-activity-name]

while creating azure blob trigger function.
Below are the things you need to check in your function logic.

If you are performing operations having dependency among files which are not yet present then skip the process, in the next trigger you can process it.
You read this log file as csv and check for the expected files to be completed according to the logic you have.

This way you can avoid too many trigger to your function.

I actually wanted to do something similar to this, and I thought the copy activity could output a list of copied files that I could use to generate a filelist txt file in blob storage, but it wasn't possible. I guess this is one way to achieve a similar result, but unfortunately unless you're willing to parse the log, you can't easily get a list of copied files to process. So this kinda works, and thanks for that, but it's far from ideal and not architecturally clean.

Yeah. you also need to check the copied files after copy activity based on that you need to call function in case of http trigger.

This hack is kinda ugly and I don't want to parse the logs... Unfortunate ADF limitation... It would be nice if Copy Activity was able to create a list of processed files (similar to delete after copy checkbox) and then we could simply react to that. ADF already can read from filelist, but cannot produce one. I've created a ticket about this: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/2b40c480-5ac7-ef11-95f5-0022484c7a61

check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006903/get-immediate-file-name-copied-using-azure-data-factory
